# Swift Coding With Milliseconds - How To Calculate?

Tags: swift

Just a question in regards to the times in Swift. I have a timestamp, which I want to validate whether it is 24 hours past the current time at the moment. I tried a few options and this is where my code is at the moment however I am stuck. Any tips will be highly appreciated!

```
let timeStampsOfUser = timeStampsOfUser.value as Any as! Double
print(timeStampsOfUser)
            
let timeInMiliSecDate = Date()
let timeInMiliSec = Double (timeInMiliSecDate.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
print(timeInMiliSec)
                                 
if timeInMiliSec - timeStampsOfUser > 86400000 {
                         
// how do I get the total count of timestamps which have been more than 24 hours and vice versa?         
                       
}
```

**Update: However, how do I found the count? As in, how many of the timestamps are more and less than 24 hours? Thanks**

```
let timeStampsOfUser = timeStampsOfUser.value as Any as! Double
print(timeStampsOfUser)
            
let timeInMiliSecDate = Date()
let timeInMiliSec = Double (timeInMiliSecDate.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
print(timeInMiliSec)
                         
let timeDone = timeInMiliSec - timeStampsOfUser > 86400000
                                 
if timeDone == true {
   print("more than 24 hours")
} else {
   print("less than 24 hours")
}
```

Comment: your example shows 1 timestamp. Where are multiple timestamps? Are they in Array, some sort of object / array of objects, CoreData, etc?

Answer (score 1):

`86400000` is the wrong approach. **Never use *86400-math***. Days could have 23 or 25 hours.

Create an extension of `Date` with 2 functions, an `init` method which takes a timestamp in milliseconds and a function to check if a given date is in the last 24 hours (actually the difference is less than one day). `Calendar` can do this with `DateComponents` pretty reliably.

```
extension Date {
    init(timestampInMilliseconds: Double) {
        self.init(timeIntervalSince1970: timestampInMilliseconds / 1000.0)
    }
    
    func isDateInLast24Hours() -> Bool {
        Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: self, to: .now).day! == 0
    }
}
```

And use it

```
let timeStamp = 1665584000000.0 // 12. Oct 2022, 16:13
let date = Date(timestampInMilliseconds: timeStamp)
let isInLast24Hours = date.isDateInLast24Hours()
```

To check multiple timestamps use a loop or `map`